# how to get value of variable config in bash?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have a linux config file with with format like this:

```
VARIABLE=5753
VARIABLE2=""
....
```

How would I get f.e. value of VARIABLE2 using standard linux tools or regular expressions?
(I need to parse directory path from file). Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe I am not getting this, but why don't you write `echo $VARIABLE2`?

Comment: you don't want to source that whole file?

Comment: It's been nearly 3 years so I don't even remember, but I think I went for right answer.
Sourcing whole config wasn't an option, I wasn't about to execute "." on potentially untrusted / corrupted config, so I went for perl regex matching thing and then filtered results by extra regulars (there was a optional name for tmpdir in variable in my script and I didnt wanted it to be "~" or "/" which would result in "rm -r ~" afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$> cat ./text 
VARIABLE=5753
VARIABLE2=""
```

With `perl` regular expression `grep` could match these value using **lookbehind**  operator.

```
$> grep --only-matching --perl-regex "(?<=VARIABLE2\=).*" ./text
""
```

And for `VARIABLE`:

```
$> grep --only-matching --perl-regex "(?<=VARIABLE\=).*" ./text
5753
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `source` (a.k.a. `.`) command to load all of the variables in the file into the current shell:

```
$ source myfile.config
```

Now you have access to the values of the variables defined inside the file:

```
$ echo $VARIABLE
5753
```

Answer (score 5):

```
eval $(grep "^VARIABLE=" configfile)
```

will select the line and evaluate it in the current bash context, setting the variable value.  After doing this, you will have a variable named `VARIABLE` with value `5753`.  If no such line exists in the configfile, nothing happens.