# how to read data from a file in shell script

Tags: shell

I have two shell script files **test1.sh and test2.sh** . I have another file called **translogs.txt**.
Now I need to copy the values of two variables in test1.sh to translog.txt and the same variables need to be copied to the corresponding values in **test2.sh**.

**test1.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
ONE="000012"
TIME="2013-02-19 15:31:06"
echo -e "$ONE\n$TIME">translog.txt;
```

**translog.txt**

```
ONE="000012"
TIME="2013-02-19 15:31:06"
```

But here in **test2.sh**, I want the same value as in translog.txt to the corresponding variable

**test2.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
ONE="000012"
TIME="2013-02-19 15:31:06"
```

Comment: I've ready our question 3 times, and still get confused over what exactly do you want to accomplish... Maybe show a before and after along with the way you're currently trying to do it?

Comment: I have achieved this test1.sh and translog.txt but I need to get values from translog.txt to test2.sh correspondingly

Comment: As I understand it, you want to read from `test2.sh` script values that are put in `translog.txt`?

Comment: I need to assign the same values in the translog.txt to same variables in test2.sh

Comment: @Blazej Kroll, yes I need to read values to test2.sh

Comment: You mean match a ONE="(.+)" and TIME="(.+)" from translog.txt and replace those values for ONE/TIME on test2.sh?

Comment: @Daniel, yes I have to get the same values for the variables in test2.sh as in translog.txt

Comment: @Vishu: have you managed to make the script work for you?

Comment: No...not yet still...working on the same

Answer (score 3):

### 1 Diry solution

```
$> cat translog.txt
ONE="000012"
TIME="2013-02-19 15:31:06"
```

With `perl` regular expression `grep` could match these value using **lookbehind**  operator.

```
$> grep --only-matching --perl-regex "(?<=ONE\=).*" translog.txt
"000012"
```

And for `TIME`:

```
$> grep --only-matching --perl-regex "(?<=TIME\=).*" translog.txt
"2013-02-19 15:31:06"
```

So from withing the `test2.sh` script you can use it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ONE=`grep --only-matching --perl-regex "(?<=ONE\=).*" translog.txt`
TIME=`grep --only-matching --perl-regex "(?<=TIME\=).*" translog.txt`
```

---

### 2 Command line solution

Another solution pointed out in one of the links below would be to use:
the `source` (a.k.a. `.`) command to load all of the variables in the file into the current shell:

```
$ source translog.txt
```

Now you have access to the values of the variables defined inside the file:

```
$ echo $TIME
"2013-02-19 15:31:06"
```

---

### 3 Easiest solution

Another approach was mentioned by @user2086768. Put these lines to `test2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval $(cat translog.txt)
```

And as a result you would have assigned the two variables within the `test2.sh` script:

```
ONE="000012"
TIME="2013-02-19 15:31:06"
```

you can easily check that adding:

```
echo $ONE
echo $TIME
```

Check also these links:

- [how to get value of variable config in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553715/how-to-get-value-of-variable-config-in-bash)
- Here's a more general overview: [Loading data into bash variables](http://af-design.com/blog/2009/07/07/loading-data-into-bash-variables/)

Comment: @StevenPenny I don't like to copy&paste another's persons answers. However, I will edit to give more details.

Comment: @BlazejKroll I get this error : **grep: ./home/db-backup/translogs.txt: No such file or directory** even when I write the correct code.

Comment: @Vishu try now, I removed the unnecessary dots in the scripts.

Comment: @Vishu I am assuming that you are running the script from the directory where the translogs.txt is placed. If not, put the correct path to the translog.txt file before it, e.g.:
grep --only-matching --perl-regex "(?<=ONE\=).*" \home\vishu\translogs.txt

Comment: @BlazejKroll It hangs while executing the script

Comment: @BlazejKroll All the three files are in the same directory

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24763/discussion-between-vishu-and-blazej-kroll)

Answer (score 1):

As `translog.txt` is valid bash code, you could do:

```
source translog.txt
```

in `test2.sh`,  `ONE` and `TWO` would be available in `test2.sh`.

A word of warning, that does open you up to shell script injection attacks if the values for `ONE` and `TWO` were to come from an untrusted source.

Answer (score 0):

If your translog.txt is as you say, then this will work

```sh
#!/bin/sh
while read aa
do
  eval "$aa"
done < translog.txt
```

Comment: It isn't working ...i got this error **command not found** at line 5

Answer (score 0):

eval should work for you.

Try to use this version of test2.sh:

**test2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
eval $(cat translog.txt)
echo $ONE
echo $TIME
```

This outputs:

000012

2013-02-19 15:31:06

Comment: @Vishu: what is the right name of the file? translogs.txt or translog.txt?