# Removing word from grep output

Tags: bash, grep, cat

I have the following bash command:

```
cat setup.py | grep name=`
```

This returns the line

```
name='SOME_PROJECTNAME',
```

How would I pipe this output from grep to just retrieve `SOME_PROJECTNAME`?

I have tried

```
cat setup.py | grep name= | tr -d 'name=','
```

but this removes characters in `SOME_PROJECTNAME`.

Comment: And/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553715/how-to-get-value-of-variable-config-in-bash, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148796/get-string-after-character, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358547/how-to-grep-for-contents-after-pattern

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep` [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
$ grep -oP "(?<=name=').*(?=')" setup.py
```

Comment: Note that `grep` manual says about `-P`: _This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features_.

Answer (score 0):

```
#bad cat setup.py | grep name= | cut -d= -f2-
cat setup.py | grep name= | cut -d' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed may be helpful here.

```
 sed -ne "s/name='\(.*\)'/\1/p" setup.py
```

The option `-n` makes sed *not* print lines by default. Then we replace the entire property line (`name='SOME_PROJECTNAME'`) with the value only (`SOME_PROJECTNAME`). The `p` flag in the `s///` command makes sed print the line *only if the replacement its executed*. So, the only line to be printed are the ones where the replacement was done, with the replaced value.

Comment: Wouldn't that return `SOME_PROJECTNAME'` (with single quote)?